# PHP inheritance self child conflicts

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, parent-child

I have class hierarchy like below.

```
class foo()
{
   function __construct($dfnname) {
      $this->callf = $dfnname;
   }
   function getd()
   {
      return call_user_func($this->callf);
   }
   function retrieve()
   {
      return $this->getd();
   }
}

class bar extends foo
{
   function getd()
   {
      return 'invalid call';
   }
   function getc()
   {
      return 'valid call';
   }
}

$ins = new bar('getc');
echo $ins->retrieve();
```

I am getting the answer `'invalid call'`. I want to get the answer 'valid call'.

It might be because of from function `foo=>retrieve()`,it calls `$this->getd()`. 
and here instead of calling `foo=>getd()`, it is directly calling `bar=>getd()`, what should I do to call `foo=>getd()` from `foo=>retrieve()` and also  `call_user_func($this->callf)` in `foo=>getd()` should call `bar=>getc()` function.

I know I am missing some basic inheritance concept. Please guide me.

Comment: bar inherits all methods from foo. If bar overloads a method (like getd()), then when you call getd(), the implementation in de bar-class is used. It is indeed basic inheritance. I think it would be ok to read a bit more on OOP in general, since most of the principles are alike across languages

Comment: yes it is calling the bar-class function when I call getd() from parent, I want to call parent getd() from parent retrieve(), any way can I get it?

Comment: No, you are missing the point of inheritance. You have an instance of bar, therefore you are calling retrieve() from the scope of bar, and retrieve() will therefore call bar::getd() and not foo::getd(). You can call the parent implementation from bar by using "return parent::getd()" which will effectively call foo::getd(), but then what added value has your bar::getd() implementation got?

Comment: You _can_ get the method from the parent, but it's not a nice solution. In order to get the parent's method, change the retrieve method to: `if (get_class($this) === 'bar') { return parent::getd();} return $this->getd();`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
class foo
{
   function __construct($dfnname) {
      $this->callf = $dfnname;
   }
   private function getd()
   {
      return call_user_func($this->callf);
   }

   private function getc()
   {

   }
   function retrieve()
   {
      return $this->getd();
   }
}

class bar extends foo
{


}

$ins = new bar('getc');
echo $ins->retrieve();
```

Did you read documentation about [Visibility in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)?